# If u is a positive harmonic function on U, the open unit disc, such that u(0)=1. Find the upper and lower bounds for u(1/2).

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

If u is a positive harmonic function on U, the open unit disc, such that u(0)=1. Find the upper and lower bounds for u(1/2).

> Note that u is only harmonic 'inside' U.

Can we estimate u(1/2) only by using the concepts of Poisson integral and Harnack inequality?
I know that u should be given by a Poisson integral of a holomorphic function defined on the boundary, which I guess to be u itself. But we have no information about u on the boundary. Could someone help??

Comment: I would suggest to take $f=u+iv, f(0)=1$ analytic and then $g=(f-1)/(f+1)$ is a disc self map for which $g(0)=0$ and see what happens; another similar idea is to use that if $f=1+\sum a_nz^n$ then $|a_n| \le 2$ so if $a_n=2$ you get $u(1/2)=3$ as upper bound achieved for $f=(1+z)/(1-z)$ and then one should get $1/3$ as lower bound by some more manipulation corresponding to $1/f$

Comment: Could you explain the second idea more explicitly?
How did you get bound for the coefficients?
Did you apply Cauchy's estimate and the mean value property?

Comment: This is a well known result that follows from the representation of positive harmonic functions (hence analytic functions with positive real part) as Poisson (Cauchy) integrals of positive measures - the maximal function being $(1+z)/(1-z)$ when $u(0)=1$

Comment: This is where I got confused. I know that u can be given by a Poisson integral of the suitable function, but how could we use this representation? In the integral formula, we have used the values of u on the boundary, like u(exp(it)), which we had no information about.

Comment: Technically one takes $u(re^{it})$ which defines a positive measure of mass $1$ on the unit circle and uses the weak star compacity of the unit ball in the space of measures to get the measure representing $u$ as a weak star limit point of the above as $r\to 1$; note that the measure representing $u$ (and $f$) may be singular like in the $(1+z)/(1-z)$ case ($u$ being the real part) where the measure is the dirac at $1$ so is singular; then the coefficient inequality just follows from the Cauchy integral wr the given measure since the measure has mass $1$